# Nginx hosting Angular SSR App + SPA on same root

Tags: angular, nginx, server-side-rendering

I cant get the nginx configuration working for hosting 2 angular apps on the same root, basically I want on the same root/domain to host a serverside rendered app and a Single page application.

**Achievement**:
The matching seems fine for the locations, on specific match we only want to proxy the requests to angular ssr on http://localhost:4000 else on all other routes and default should render the Single Page Application. The routing works.

E.g.
https://dev.mysite.dk/ -> hits / location, render normal angular spa
https://dev.mysite.dk/someslug/blog -> hit /blog location, proxy request to angular ssr

folder structure, both projects in individual folders:
/var/www/html

**ISSUE**:
The index.html file that is returned from angular ssr needs to load js chunk files and css, but it always fails with wrong mime type error (essentially meaning file was not found, and 404 docment was returned).

index file for SSR:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>MY site</title>
    <base href="/seo/" />
```

Initially the issue was that these requests ended up matching the / location, which is for the Angular SPA.

Tried adding base href in the index.html file from angular ssr to
/seo/ and then added a new location block that matches it, which also proxies the requests to http://localhost:4000. Still no luck.

Please let me know if this is even possible to do, or if I'm missing something obvious.

```
server {
      listen        443 ssl http2;
      listen        [::]:443 ssl http2;
      access_log off;
      server_name   dev.mysite.dk; 
      ssl_certificate       /etc/letsencrypt/live/dev.mysite.dk/fullchain.pem;
      ssl_certificate_key    /etc/letsencrypt/live/dev.mysite.dk/privkey.pem;

    location ~* /seo/ {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:4000;
    }

    location ~* (^/hh|^/tips|^/blog) {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:4000;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_request_buffering off;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        client_body_temp_path /tmp/;
        client_body_in_file_only on;
        client_body_buffer_size 1m;
        client_max_body_size 50m;
        client_body_timeout 60s;
        proxy_intercept_errors on;
        error_page 404 = /404;
    }
 

      location / {
          dav_methods PUT DELETE;
          root /var/www/html/web;
          index index.html;
          try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }
    }
```

Error on the browser:
[image]